# Java - Help needed with file reading

Tags: java, file

```
public void readFile() throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.txt"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pracListTeacherTable.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{line, line});

}
```

Hey everyone. I have this piece of code that essentially reads from a file called `Data.txt`. What I want is for each 2 lines of the text file to create 1 row on the table, however as you can see I'm using `model.addRow(new Object[]{line, line});` which uses the same line for both cells of the same Row.

I need some way to store the previous line so I can have something like `model.addRow(new Object[]{line, nextline});` however I can't figure out how to do it!

If anyone could help me out that would be amazing.

**Update: Got it working thanks to shaoyihe!**

```
public void readFile() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.txt"))) {
    String line1, line2;
    while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null && (line2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pracListTeacherTable.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{line1,line2});
    }        
}
```

Comment: Okay so you have the current line and just simply save the previous line in a `String prevLine;` and you should be good...

Answer (score 0):

What about read two lines at every loop ?

```
String line1, line2;
while ((line1 = reader.readLine()) != null && (line2 = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//model.addRow(new Object[]{line1, line2});
}

// for odd line
if (line1 != null) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it and get back to you with my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public void readFile() throws IOException
{
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Data.txt"))) {
    String line;
    String [] lines = new String[2];
    int nextLine = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        lines[nextLine++] = line;
        // check if we're at the second line
        if (nextLine == 2) {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) pracListTeacherTable.getModel();
            model.addRow(lines);
            nextLine = 0;
        }
    }
    if (nextLine == 1) {
        // odd number of lines in file (error?)
        // lines[0] contains the odd (last) line
        // lines[1] contains the previous line (last of the previous pair)
    }
}
```

Would it make sense to retrieve the model once before the loop? or does `getModel()` return a different model on each call?